# Python Numpy add 3 arrays in one array

Tags: python, numpy

I'm quite new in Numpy and I don´t know how to solve this problem.

I have these arrays:

```
one = np.array(np.ones(3))   --> [ 1.  1.  1.]
two = np.array(np.zeros(3))  --> [ 0.  0.  0.]
three = np.array([1,2,3]) -->    [ 1  2  3]
```

I would like to create an array that holds these three arrays in this way:

```
[[ 1.  1.  1.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.]
 [ 1.  2.  3.]]
```

thanks

Comment: `np.array([one, two, three])`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
np.vstack((one, two, three))
```

Read about vstack [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vstack.html#numpy.vstack)

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> one=np.array(np.ones(3))
>>> two=np.array(np.zeros(3))
>>> three=np.array([1,2,3])
>>> one
array([ 1.,  1.,  1.])
>>> two
array([ 0.,  0.,  0.])
>>> three
array([1, 2, 3])
>>> matrix=np.array([one,two,three])
>>> matrix
array([[ 1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  2.,  3.]])
>>>
```